# Updating positional data in a list when deleting arbitrary rows

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Suppose I have a simple object consisting of fields 'Position' and 'Value' where position is an integer that indicates the 'row' that data belongs to.

How can I ensure 'Position' is updated correctly (the position field is decremented by the correct number where appropriate) if arbitrary rows are deleted?

E.g. The data list looks like:

> [ { Position: 1, Value: "1" }, { Position: 2, Value: "2" }, {
>   Position: 3, Value: "3" }... ]

Assuming I know which rows have been deleted as I have a list of them e.g. [2,3,4] or [2,4] etc.

The deleted row numbers may not be consecutive and there may be multiple objects with the same position. The data is not necessarily ordered by position in the data list.

I'm sure there must be a relatively simple algorithm for achieving this efficiently but I haven't worked it out yet.

Comment: Are the objects arranged by their position? Also, are we assuming that the deleted rows are deleted all at the same time, or one by one?

Comment: As above 'the data is not necessarily ordered by position' so no the objects are not arranged by their position. Multiple rows may be deleted at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have 3 ideas of how to achieve this. 
The problem is that ALL rows should be deleted at once & the fact that the deleted row numbers may not be consecutive. Meaning that simply modifying the object's position by looping through the deleted rows list is not going to work (it will be a one by one instead all at once). So my ideas are:

> idea 1: Create a copy of the objects list. When reading the value from
>   the original list, and if you found the deleted row that is below that
>   object's position, you decrement the position of the object in your
>   copied list instead of the original one. You can simply set the
>   original list to that copied list after the process.
>
> idea 2: You could add a new attribute to the object, something like
>   "fallDistance". Which is going to store how much the object is going
>   be reduced. So, after looping through the deleted rows list, you
>   update the objects's position based on that value.
>
> idea 3: Arrange your list of deleted rows, so that iterating through
>   them from the top will guarantee a correct final result. This works
>   for both iterating through the deleted rows list and iterating through
>   the object list.

my guess is that algorithm 3 will work the fastest, mainly because there are very little things to do. It really depends on what language you use, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. This helped me to realise that the right thing to do is sort the data list first by position and believe I have a solution that will work based on this.

Essentially the algorithm would be:

1. Sort data by position
2. Remove objects marked for deletion (if any - if not do not proceed)
3. Iterate through the data, with a counter for the new position (starting from 1), and a marker for the old position. Set the position of each object to the counter value. When data with a position higher than the marker is encountered set the marker to that position and increment the counter.